# What is the most intuitive way for users to understand inclusive and exclusive filters?

Tags: interaction-design, filter, browser

We are not sure how to show a filter options in a chrome extension. The extension filters RSS contents, and we need to set the type of the filter:

- inclusive filter
- exclusive filter

If we select inclusive filter, all the tags (in a free text box), are inclusive in the filter.

If we select exclusive filter, all the tags (in a free text box), are exclusive in the filter.

We need select one option, inclusive or exclusive.

When we select one the two options, we need set the operator AND or OR, between all the tags.

Which would be the most intuitive way for users to understand it?

Comment: Can you include an illustration of what your filter control looks like today?

Comment: Could you give more context? I don't know what you mean with inclusive and exclusive filters. And will it be in a drop down menu in the top right corner of the browser? Or will it be on a complete page?

Comment: They enter tag values in free text box?   Using the term filter for exclusive is like a double negative and will confuse users.  I would just drop filter for "Include Tags" and "Exclude Tags".  User don't have to know exclude is an OR as that behavior will be the logical behavior to most users.

Answer (score 2):

Do wish to implement is the ability for the user to click on a row/column and be presented with the option of either filtering out all such column values or to include only those column values?

If I have understood correct, here is what I think could solve your problem. This is not the best practise we follow when we use filter criteria but considering your use case, you may go with this approach. Include and Exclude is kind of toggle button which you can select one at a time. There is a filter icon for each column header.

I just modified one of my grid to showcase example on how may look. See if this is helpful for you.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would just say it. I don't think there is a need to try to use Venn diagrams or something like that to make users to understand what inclusive or exclusive means.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXUjd7.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Then again, do you really need to use these kind of filters? Do you have data to back up the decision to use this kind of design?